# ERROR: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'editorUpload' of null when trying to add a IMG

Tags: javascript, image, null, tinymce

We have a page on our internal website that uses TinyMCE's RichText editor in a few places.  One of those places is a partial view that pops up when a user clicks on a button.  That is the only place this error appears.  This error happens when the user tries to Insert a picture either by using the ToolBar icon or the menu -> Insert -> Picture.  The file-picker window comes up fine, it's after you select your file (from your PC) that this error appears in the Browser's console window.

Here's the code:

```
    <head>
<script>
        tinymce.init({
            selector: '.BtCEditor',
            plugins: 'powerpaste lists image link searchreplace emoticons',
            toolbar: 'powerpaste | image imagetools undo redo | styleselect | bold italic charmap | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify link | lists numlist outdent indent | emoticons ',
            powerpaste_block_drop: false,
            powerpaste_allow_local_images: true,
            automatic_uploads: true,
            file_picker_types: 'image',
            file_picker_callback: function (cb, value, meta) {
                var input = document.createElement('input');
                input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
                input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');
                input.onchange = function () {
                    var file = this.files[0];
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function () {
                        var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
                        
                        var blobCache = tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache; /* tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload <-- this is coming up NULL */
                        var base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
                        var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
                        blobCache.add(blobInfo);

                        /* call the callback and populate the Title field with the file name */
                        cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                };

                input.click();
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>

....

AND

<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Description, new {@class = "BtCEditor"})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Description)
</div>
```

The only thing I can think of that's causing this is the TinyMCE JS is also used on the page BEFORE the user clicks on the button that brings up the PartialView.  So basically it's getting used twice.  Perhaps tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload is null because it's already in use?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Discovered that the partial view ALSO had the register API key.  So it was being duplicated (once in the footer, once in the partial view) and that was the error.  Once removed and only used Tiny.Init() it worked fine.